# Return array from function with specified key and it's value

Tags: php

```
function do_get_array() {

    $posts[] = array(
        'name'          => 'Page',
        'icon'          => 'fa fa-users',
        'fields'        => array(
            array(
                'field_name'       => 'Publisher Logo',
                'id'               => 'pub_logo',
                'type'             => 'text',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $posts[] = array(
        'name'          => 'Slideshow',
        'icon'          => 'fa fa-users',
        'fields'        => array(
            array(
                'field_name'       => 'Publisher Logo2',
                'id'               => 'pub_logob',
                'type'             => 'text',
            ),
        ),
    );
return $posts;

}
```

getting arrays from above function.

```
$posts = do_get_array();
$return = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $return['name'] = $post['name'];
    $return['icon'] = $post['icon'];

}
print_r($return);
```

but it only returns second array.
I want it to return all the arrays value with key that i provided.
I am actually new to php that's why i think i have some confusion.

Comment: You are overwriting your values in the loop: `$return['name'] = ...`. Why do you need a new array?

Comment: `foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $return[] = ['name' => $post['name'], 'icon' => $post['icon']];
}`

Comment: but I want it to return with the key. like this.
Array ( [name] => Page [icon] => fa fa-users ) 
Array ( [name] => Slideshow [icon] => fa fa-users )

Comment: Should be `$return[] = ['name' => $post['name'], 'icon' => $post['icon']]; `and  `$posts` should be declared somewhere as an (empty?) array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting each time.  Build an array of those arrays:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) 
    $return[] = array('name' => $post['name'], 'icon' => $post['icon']);
}
```

However this seems like a waste, you could just use the `$posts` array as is, it just has some extra information.

If you actually want the name as the array index, then:

```
$return[$post['name']] = $post['icon'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your function the second $posts[] override the first one.

try this to merge the tow $posts[]:

```
<?php
function do_get_array() {
$posts1[] = array(
        'name'          => 'Page',
        'icon'          => 'fa fa-users',
        'fields'        => array(
                                array(
                                    'field_name'       => 'Publisher Logo',
                                    'id'               => 'pub_logo',
                                    'type'             => 'text',
                ),
        ),
);

$posts2[] = array(
        'name'          => 'Slideshow',
        'icon'          => 'fa fa-users',
        'fields'        => array(
                array(
                        'field_name'       => 'Publisher Logo2',
                        'id'               => 'pub_logob',
                        'type'             => 'text',
                ),
        ),
);

$result = array_merge($posts1, $posts2);
return $result;
}

$posts = do_get_array();
$return = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($posts); $i++){
    $return[$i]['name'] = $posts[$i]['name'];
    $return[$i]['icon'] = $posts[$i]['icon'];
}

print_r($return);
```